# Flutter + Firebase Throwing Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted Error Using Navigator to change view

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase driven Flutter app that is working but throwing errors.

What I expected, when the app is open the user has to login using an email and password, if the login succeeds then they are taken the a new view called WelcomeScreen.

What is happening, the users are being taken to a welcome screen after logging in but I get the following errors

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
#0      State.context.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1088:9)
#1      State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1094:6)
#2      _AuthScreenState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:autos_latinos/screens/auth_screen.dart:81:35)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
#5      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#7      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
#8      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
#9      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closur<…>
```

It seems to be pointing to this part here in my code which I use to track authStateChanges from firebase:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
        if(AuthScreen.id != '/AuthScreen'){
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen()));
        }else{
          print("Already on auth screen");
        }


      } else {
        //Send to welcome screen
        print('User is signed in!');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeScreen()));
      }
    });
```

Any Advice on how to prevent this error is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Do you find the solution? I need to solve this in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to dispose the listener in `dispose` method of stateful widget like this:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  StreamSubscription<User> _listener;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _listener = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
        if (AuthScreen.id != '/AuthScreen') {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthScreen()));
        } else {
          print("Already on auth screen");
        }
      } else {
        //Send to welcome screen
        print('User is signed in!');
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeScreen()));
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _listener.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I gave that a try but its still giving me the following error ```[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _LoginCardState#bf03a(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted, tickers: tracking 0 tickers)```